# How do I prevent Tenno from landing into a roll?

Tags: warframe

When falling from a certain height, my character often executes a roll landing. Sometimes this gets her into line of fire or off of ledges -- and into line of fire. Is there a way to prevent this roll and land into a normal crouch?

I've tried moving in the direction opposite to where I'm falling and releasing movement controls entirely, but it still seems that she will decide to roll pretty much at random. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't prevent a landing motion. You can either roll or turn the roll into a slide by turning the camera perpendicular to your direction of motion.

While this is speculation, common sense suggests that the roll is required for a reason: to break your momentum. Rolling is a standard way of minimizing damage from an impact, so it makes sense that it would be required. Think of it as your Tenno not being offered the option to land without rolling because it would break his legs. Of course in some situations like falling straight down this doesn't really make sense, but its the best they could do.

Comment: Oh, I know why you would want to roll in real life. However, Warframe isn't a game famous for its realism, and Tenno seem to survive long falls without rolling just fine - it essentially stuns them for a second, but sometimes that is preferrable to rolling into line of fire.

Comment: Plus, since I use a tank loadout, if I start reloading or charging my weapon and I roll, I lose the charge,which is about the most frustrating thing with some of the weapons.

Comment: @Pvt.Grichmann yeah I just put it there as a reference. Regardless, you cannot prevent a roll or slide while the game thinks you are in "parkour mode". There are a number of threads from a while ago complaining about it, it was added in Update 10 of the beta.

Comment: Alright, then. It seems to me that whether you roll/slide or land on your hands and feet depends on how fast you're moving horizontally. Annoying when sprinting off of short stairs. But you're right, it isn't directly controllable. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Good news! DE recently released an update that completely prevented rolling from ever occuring unless you drop from high distances while moving forward.

Meaning, as long as you drop from high distance while not moving forwards, you'll never have to see a rolling animation ever again!

Answer (score 1):

Try using the ground slam attack with your melee while in mid-air.

Answer (score 0):

Try wallrunning, then jumping away from sight. Possibly wallrun while sprinting (up) and then do the flying kick into the whatever you were on and you won't roll. Has not been tested on PC.